# Determine if string from argv[1] starts with a character or number (C-programming)

Tags: c, string, parameters, argv

I'm writing a small application in C that takes two parameters. One is a filename, the other a number, and they may be specified in random order.

> ./main filename 12345

and

> ./main 12345 filename

should both work.

How can I easily determine which is which when I know the filename starts with a character?

Comment: And if the filename is a number?

Comment: I guess in that case, you'll have to use the second syntax or you'll confuse the program :)

Comment: As I wrote: the filename starts with a character.

Comment: Why don't you just require the arguments to be in a specific order?  That's what most programs do, since otherwise it's impossible to determine the arguments.  Most programs do have to deal with filenames which are numbers.

Comment: What do you do with a filename that starts with a dash? Or a $? Adam, you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions (defined in `ctype.h`) on the first character of `argv[1]` or `argv[2]`.

Comment: The main problem with every solution like this comes if you have a filename which is a legal number. So you would have to check the whole string if it only consists of a number and then also if it is no existing file.

Comment: @frenetisch, that would not be a problem with this answer, but with the question itself. And it's not even a problem with the question since the OP states that all the filenames start with a character.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ctype functions.

```
if (isalpha(*argv[1]))
    // argv[1] starts with a letter
else if (isdigit(*argv[1])
    // argv[1] starts with a number
```

Comment: And don't forget to handle the `else` case as well... `./main /path/to/file 666`. Just using isdigit(), and presuming filename otherwise is probably better.

Comment: You should cast `*argv[1]` to `unsigned char`, since it is of type `char`, and `isalpha` and `isdigit` specify that their argument must be in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isdigit`.

```
isdigit((unsigned char)argv[1][0])
```

Make sure you check `argc` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ('0' <= argv[1][0] && argv[1][0] <= '9')
{
    /* it starts with a number */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `sscanf()` function, which returns the number of successfully scanned items:

```
int number;
char *string;

if (sscanf (argv[1], " %d ", &number) == 1) { /*12345 filename */
  string = malloc ((strlen (argv[2]) + 1) * sizeof (char));
  sscanf (argv[2], " %s ", string);
}
else { /* filename 12345 */
  sscanf (argv[2], " %d ", &number);
  string = malloc ((strlen (argv[1]) + 1) * sizeof (char));
  sscanf (argv[1], " %s ", string);
}
```

If `argv[1]` is a string starting with a character the first clause will return "zero".

Comment: There's no need to copy strings in this case, you can just assign `string` directly to `argv[1] or `argv[2]` as appropriate.

Comment: You are right, Adam, they're within same scope. Thanks for pointing that out.